# Run plist on wake

Tags: shell, launchd, launchdagent

I've been searching all over and found options at [launchd](http://www.launchd.info/) site. Is there a way to launch a `.plist` on machine wake? If this is not possible is there a way to run a shell script without installing another package and just use plain shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first it didn't work on my OSX Sierra mac. After restarting my machine the plist configuration seems to work now.

```
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
```

This key makes sure that your `plist` runs at wake and if you want to specify which script it will run you can do so by

```
<dict>
    <key>PathState</key>
    <dict>
        <key>/path/to/your/shell/script.sh</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```